# Variable 'Name' is used before it has been assigned a value

Tags: vb.net

hello i wanted to make a chat and i searched on the internet and i finaly found something that may work. but now i get an error at name it says Variable Name is used before it has assigned a value

Code:

```
Public Sub findForm1()

    If Trim(Mid(My.Forms.Private1.Text, My.Forms.Private1.Text.Length - 2)) = formNo Then
        My.Forms.Private1.RichTextBox1.Text = My.Forms.Private1.RichTextBox1.Text & poruka + vbCrLf

    ElseIf Trim(Mid(My.Forms.Private2.Text, My.Forms.Private2.Text.Length - 2)) = formNo Then
        My.Forms.Private2.RichTextBox1.Text = My.Forms.Private2.RichTextBox1.Text & poruka + vbCrLf

    Else
        If My.Forms.Private1.Visible = False Then
            Dim name As String
            For i As Integer = 1 To poruka.Length
                If Mid(poruka, i, 2) = ": " Then
                    Exit For

                    name = name & Mid(poruka, i, 1)
                End If
            Next
            My.Forms.Private1.Show()
            My.Forms.Private1.Text = Trim(name) & "   " & br
            My.Forms.Private1.RichTextBox1.Text = My.Forms.Private1.RichTextBox1.Text & poruka + vbCrLf
        Else
            Dim name As String
            For i As Integer = 1 To poruka.Length
                If Mid(poruka, i, 2) = ": " Then
                    Exit For
                End If
                name = name & Mid(poruka, i, 1)
            Next
            My.Forms.Private2.Show()
            My.Forms.Private2.Text = Trim(name) & "   " & br
            My.Forms.Private2.RichTextBox1.Text = My.Forms.Private2.RichTextBox1.Text & poruka + vbCrLf
        End If
    End If

    formNo = Nothing
    poruka = Nothing

End Sub
```

how can i fix this error??
i already tried to move the end if and change some else to end if.
but still not find the right code PLEAS HELP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the compiler's absolutely right. The problem in your code can be boiled down to something like this:

```
Dim name as String
name = name & "Foo"
```

You're trying to concatenate the *current* value of `name` with another string ("Foo") - but `name` doesn't *have* a value yet.

You could change it to:

```
Dim name as String = ""
name = name & "Foo"
```

... but you'd be better off using a `StringBuilder`. So for example, your first loop could be:

```
Dim nameBuilder As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
For i As Integer = 1 To poruka.Length
    If Mid(poruka, i, 2) = ": " Then
        Exit For

        nameBuilder.Append(Mid(poruka, i, 1))
    End If
Next
My.Forms.Private1.Show()
My.Forms.Private1.Text = Trim(nameBuilder.ToString()) & "   " & br
```

Comment: haha thanks i already fixed the problem but you`ve explained it to me. what i tried was dim name as string = nothing and it worked i dont know why but it worked until now XD

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there are a couple of scenarios that could lead to your variable never being initialised. To fix, simply give a default value e.g.

```
Dim Name As String = ""
```

Also, you are re-declaring the same variable twice, you only need to do this once, just clear it again if you need it to be "blank" for the next loop or use 2 separate variables (I.e. more specifically named) instead.

Comment: You mean `""`, not `''`. And it's not just getting to the end of the loop - there's also *within* the loop.

Comment: @JonSkeet yeah realised that after I had posted, on my generic mobile device :) I updated to be more general as I didn't notice it was being used outside the for as well.