# VB.NET Add Path to Exception Message

Tags: vb.net, exception

I am trying to add the path and file name of files that throw exceptions (see image attached). My code works but Visual Studio Community Edition 2015 (VB.NET 4.6) reports "Variable 'FileName' is used before it is assigned a value...". Can anyone suggest how I can remove this issue, or whether this is ok to ignore? I am new to VB.NET and would be happy to reformat my code if there is a better way to do this.

Regards

George

[image]

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1u1K.jpg]

Comment: your image is sort of messed up

Comment: It is a warning, not an error. It is okay to ignore if you know what you're doing.

Comment: Duplicate of [Variable 'Name' is used before it has been assigned a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262377/variable-name-is-used-before-it-has-been-assigned-a-value)

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
Dim FileName as String = Nothing 'String.Empty 'C#: null
```

Comment: Thankyou GSerg. "Dim FileName As String = Nothing" removed the warning.